# Relativistic EDM Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, dipole-moment

The non-relativistic Hamiltonian arising from an electric dipole moment of a fermion is given by $H=\vec{d}\cdot \vec{E} = d\frac{\vec{s}}{s}\cdot \vec{E}$.  The corresponding relativistic Lagrangian is $L=-d\frac{i}{2}\bar{\psi}\sigma^{\mu\nu}\gamma_5\psi F_{\mu\nu}$, according to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0504231) (eq. 2.2).

**Question:** Given the Hamiltonian above, how does one derive the corresponding Lagrangian?